# Dividing a 4D array image data into cells

Tags: arrays, image, matlab, multidimensional-array, cell-array

I have 22000 cell nuclei images which i have stored as a 4D data. Each image is of dimensions 27 by 27 by 3 and they are stored in nuclei4DArrayData  as [27 27 3 22000]

Now I want to split this 4D Array into cells such that I have 1x22000 cell array in which each cell has 27x27x3 image data matrix.

I have tried using mat2cell, num2cell but I cannot get the dimension parameter to split it in a way I require. 
I could manually assign each image to a cell array using the for loop but, is there any direct method or am not able to use the mat2cell function. Just want to know if it is possible using the MATLAB functions.

Comment: Why do you want to split them into cells? They are probably better as a 4D array. You can always access the `k`-th image as `nuclei4DArrayData(:,:,:,k)`

Comment: It's required as 2D cell array in a predefined function. Also, I want to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function [`num2cell`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2cell.html) should work for this, along with a call to [`reshape`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) afterwards. Starting with your data in a matrix called `data`:

```
cellData = reshape(num2cell(data, 1:3), 1, []);
```

Comment: nope, It still gives 4D cell array. This could be directly obtained from just num2cell(data) too. What I want is 2 dimensional cell array of dimensions 1x 22000 in which each cell column has an image.

Comment: @Suvidha: Ah, I see, Answer updated. You just need a reshape afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

This also works, and I find slightly more readable. I tested it and it takes exactly the same time to run.

```
 data = zeros(27, 27, 3, 22000);
 cellData = squeeze(num2cell(data, 1:3));
```

[squeeze](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/squeeze.html) function removes singleton dimensions. I tested its running time and it is the same as reshaping.

Comment: `squeeze` works, but creates a 22000-by-1 cell array instead of a 1-by-22000 cell array.